# Django TrigramSimilarity returns errors with Full Text Search on GIN index

Tags: python, django, postgresql, full-text-search, pg-trgm

Hello I'm trying to make search on Django with postgresql/FTS on a GIN indexed column but get a weird error. This error does ot appear on CharField but only on a SearchVectorField:

the Postgresql Database has the pg_trgm extension installed (within a Django migrations)

This is the Objects :

```
class Language(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5, verbose_name=_("code"))
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_("label"))
    search = SearchVectorField(null=True)

    objects = Language_Manager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("language")
        verbose_name_plural = _("languages")
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(fields=["search"], name="search_index",),
        ]

    def save(self):
        fields = [x for x in dir(self) if x[:5] == "label"]
        labels = [getattr(self, field) for field in fields if getattr(self, field)]
        self.search = self.search + " ".join(labels)
        super().save()
```

and here is my query :

```
from core.models import Language as LanguageCode
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity

LanguageCode.objects.all().annotate(sim=TrigramSimilarity("search", "english"))
```

it returns an error message :

```
LINE 1: ...e_language"."label_ko", "core_language"."search", SIMILARITY...
                                                            ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

if I use a standard *CharField* instead of a GIN indexed *SearchVectorField*, the error does not occurs :

```
from core.models import Language as LanguageCode
from django.contrib.postgres.search import TrigramSimilarity

LanguageCode.objects.all().annotate(sim=TrigramSimilarity("label", "english"))
```

```
<MultilingualQuerySet [<Language: Language object (fr)>, <Language: Language object (en)>, >><Language: Language object (it)>, ...
```

am-I doing something wrong ?

---

I'm also using Django-model-translation with the label column of this object:

```
from modeltranslation.translator import translator, TranslationOptions
from core.models import Language

class LanguageTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ("label",)

translator.register(Language, LanguageTranslationOptions)
```

Comment: I don't think you can use search vectors and trigram similarity together, like you are trying to do. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884309/postgresql-full-text-search-and-trigram-confusion) question, it may help you understand your problem.

Comment: ok that makes sense.
I have spend hours reading answers on other posts but this one is limpid. TRigramSimilarity wont search over a SerachVectorField. Thanks for your help.